# VBA: How to get a (more) dynamic file name?

Tags: excel, vba, filenames

So I have a currently working VBA script. I just want to edit the name by which the loop saves files.

I'll give a quick description of what it is currently doing. Basically it loops a set of actions for a defined range of rows, here `A2:A72`. The is a 'main' workbook where this loop is done is where all the input data is collected. Each row is a separate subject's input data and is copy/pasted into a template in a different workbook. Solver is then run to adjust the template for the given input data. Then it saves and names file as the text in the first cell of the row that was copy pasted. (ie `A2`,`A3`,`A4`,etc..) It then loops this for every row and every row will have its own template set up and saved separately.

This is ALMOST how I ideally want it to work.

I just want it save the File name not just as `A2`, but as `=C2&" - "&A2`

I tried using this that was suggested by someone

```
fName = Range("C" & c.Row) & Range("A" & c.Row)
```

But when I tried I would get a Method SaveAs error. On the watch view I could see it was because it wasn't reading the fName so it was just the file path in the script value. I changed it back to c.Value and then it started working by naming the file as the A column cell. Admittedly, I don't really understand how c.Value is returning column A which makes it harder for me to figure out how to modify it to get what I want.

Anyway here is the script as I currently have it:

```
Sub RunModels()

Dim fPath As String
Dim strTemplate As String
Dim fName As String
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim c As Range
Dim rngLoop As Range

'Where will files get stored?

fPath = "H:\ACQUISITIONS\Personal (D-AP)\Gmo\ALL MF"

'Where is the template file?
strTemplate = "H:\ACQUISITIONS\Personal (D-AP)\Gmo\ALL MF\Garden Grove - 11121 Chapman Ave.xlsm"

'Error check
If Right(fPath, 1) <Application.PathSeparator Then
    fPath = fPath & Application.PathSeparator
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Set Loop
Set rngLoop = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A72")

'Set Looped Actions
For Each c In rngLoop.Cells
    'Open the template file
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(strTemplate)
    'Add some data to the template file
    c.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=wb.Worksheets("Insert
Sheet").Range("A2")
     SolverOk SetCell:="$H$20", MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=1.2, ByChange:="$F$35", Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverSolve
    'Dynamic File Naming
    fName = c.Value
    'Save the file and close
    wb.SaveAs Filename:=wb.Path & Application.PathSeparator & fName
    wb.Close
Next c

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Thank you very very much for all and any help!!

Comment: Is it possible that you have the same value in more than 1 cell in your range and its complaining because file already exists with that name?

Comment: If you do `fName = Range("C" & c.Row).Value & Range("A" & c.Row).Value`, then after it add `msgbox fName`, what pops up? Are you sure it's a legitimate path with the `\` in the right places? If `C2` has `C:\User\MyName` and `A2` has `MyFolder\test.xlsx`, then `fName` will be `C:\User\MyNameMyFolder\test.xlsx`, and note the missing `\` separating `MyName` and `MyFolder`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use `wb.Path` `wb` is assigned to the workbook, where `fPath` is your folder path, so use:

```
Filename:=fPath & "\" & fName & ".xlsx"
```

or ".xlsm" as required.

To assign `fName` use:

```
fName = c.Offset(, 2).Value & " - " & c.Value
```

Answer (score 0):

The code assigns the variable c to each cell in the range A2:A72 in turn - so at the moment it is saving the code 71 times. The code

```
  fName = Range("C" & c.Row) & Range("A" & c.Row)
```

would produce c2 & A2 on the first time through, and then C3 & A3 on the second (and so on.  I suspect you'd like it to always use c2 and then add the value in A - in which case you'd need

```
 Fname = Range("C2") & "- "  & c
```

Comment: The OP wants to save each row to a new file using the template.